# Justify text beamer poster

Tags: beamerposter

I was trying to modify the style of this template (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/dreuw-deselaers-poster).

I can not justify the text inside of each block. I tried modifying the style and tex archives. Is there any solution for that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are all `item`s. Put `\usepackage{ragged2e}` in the preamble and use `\item\justifying some text` instead of `\item`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Looks like an answer to me

Answer (score 2):

The contents inside the block are items. Hence you can add the following in your preamble.

```
.
.
.
.
\usepackage{ragged2e}    %% provides \justifying
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\olditem\justifying}
\begin{document}
```

So that all of them get justified. If you want to do it on individual basis, use

```
\item\justifying
```

[image]